# Sending base64'd image over JSON to PHP GD libraries

Tags: php, javascript, json, base64, gd

So I send the base64 image text to the php file with jquery/javascript like this:

```
//Upload picture
$('#uploadPictureBtnHtml').click(function(){
    OpenLoader();
   var baseEncPicData = $('#chosenPictureData').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', url:'upload_picture.php',  dataType:"json",  data:{ PicFile: baseEncPicData },
        success:function (upload_pic_data) {
            if (upload_pic_data[0] == 'true') {
                    alert("it worked!");
                    CloseLoader();
            }
            else{
                    //upload_pic_data[1] will return PHP errors
                    alert("Why it didnt work: "+upload_pic_data[1]+" ");
                    CloseLoader();
            }
        }
        });
});
```

I know this works fine because if I take the `baseEncPicData` variable and output it like this:

```
$('#some_div').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+baseEncPicData+'" />');
```

It works just great and the image shows without an issue.

When I send this to the PHP file, I decode and "reassemble" it like this:

```
$dataUno = htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['PicFile'])));
$dataDos = base64_decode($dataUno);
$data = imagecreatefromstring($dataDos);
$the_new_png = imagepng($data, $the_directory);
```

The error I receive is only in PHP which is:

```
 imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Empty string or invalid image
 imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Which leads me to believe that it's not decoding the JSON correctly because there are characters being stripped that are part of the base64'd image. This is just an assumption.
Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be awesome. Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['PicFile'])));` - what for?

Comment: That decodes the JSON. Unless there's a better way of doing it. I've been doing it like this for along time so I wouldn't be surprised if a better way came out to decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this string:

`htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['PicFile'])))`;

... and process just `$_POST['PicFile']` instead. With that preprocessing you turn all `+` characters (allowed in Base64) into spaces (), effectively broking the binary.

Comment: I appreciate you answering this, going to try this now.